# change the border of an edittext in a click

Tags: android

I have 9 edittext of square form with border I wish when one clicks on an edittext among the 9 edittext the color of border of this edittext changes ....
I need your support my friends
I tried with this code but it does not execute
****1st border code border1

****2st border code "border2"

java code

```
        et1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                    et1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border2);
                    et2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
                    et9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);
            valeur = "1";
            return true;

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onClickListener() as you want to change on each click, you can do something like this :

```
etEmailAdress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (res == R.drawable.black) {
            res = R.drawable.btn_green;
        } else {
            res = R.drawable.black;
        }
        etEmailAdress.setBackgroundResource(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: int res = R.drawable.black; // Your default background
its your current border color

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using a selector and defining states. What you should do is create a layout in `drawable` folder called `edit_text_background.xml` for instance and add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/border2" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/border1"  android:state_focused="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

and then just set this new drawable as the background of each `EditText`. When it is focused (clicked) it will show `R.id.border2` and when it's not focused it will show `R.id.border1`